# how to filter only internet packets (not local) in TCP/IP?

Tags: ip, tcp, packet-analysis

I have a **packet sniffer** that mean i can read all packets sent or received to the computer(with all headers like src & dst IP:PORT).

I want to filter packets that sent/received to/from **internet** (***only*** *remote hosts that* **doesn't exist in my network**).

is there a solution for this?

---

**P.S:** i exclude packets that src or dst is in local range like **"10.0.0.0/8"** or **"192.168.0.0/16"** and other local ranges. Then result is better but not exact and i need more accurate result.

Comment: You have cross-posted this question on multiple SE sites. You need to pick one site and delete the question on the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IANA maintains the [*IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml) and [*IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml) pages. You can filter any ranges marked as False under Globally Reachable, plus the multicast ranges (`224.0.0.0/4` for IPv4 and `ff00::/8` for IPv6). Anything else is a valid, public IP address that can be used on the public Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude packets where the source *and* the destination address are in the local range.

Answer (score 0):

The packets for internal (local) network are transmitted to the local hosts directly.
The packets from/to internet are always passed through the router.
So if you make a filter getting packet from/to the router, you can get the packets from/to the internet.